# JPQL queries in Springboot 3.2.0 fails when the `+` operator is used

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I upgrade springboot 3.1.5 to 3.2.0. 
My DBMS is mySQL.

I have this JPQL.

```
@Query(
      value =
          "UPDATE parentPath pp SET pp.path = "
              + "CONCAT(:toPath, SUBSTRING(path, CHAR_LENGTH(:fromPath)+1)) WHERE pp.path LIKE :fromPath%")
  @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
  int replacePath(@Param("fromPath") String fromPath, @Param("toPath") String toPath);
```

This works fine in springboot 3.1.5 but in springboot 3.2.0, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with the message "Operand of + is of type 'java.lang.Object' which is not a numeric type (it is not an instance of 'java.lang.Number', 'java.time.Temporal', or 'java.time.TemporalAmount')." The issue is related to an incorrect use of the + operator in a Hibernate query.
```

Why is this? Why suddenly the JPQL fails?

I tried using LENGTH instead of CHAR_LENGTH and the error disappear.

Is LENGTH ok for a JPQL, database is mySQL?

Comment: Try character_length https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_mysql_character_length.asp ,
 length will give you length of string in bytes and i dont know if this is desirable

Comment: Yup, thanks, I saw it too but I am having second thoughts, I think CHARACTER_LENGTH will do,,,,

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a problem with the return type of some functions in Dialect.
I got this same message while converting date to numeric using TO_DAYS() function, like:

```
TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE()) - TO_DAYS(myField) < 0
```

It only worked when I declared the function TO_DAYS() in my custom dialect with integer return type, like this:

```
    @Override
public void initializeFunctionRegistry(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
    super.initializeFunctionRegistry(functionContributions);

    final BasicTypeRegistry basicTypeRegistry = functionContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getBasicTypeRegistry();
    final SqmFunctionRegistry functionRegistry = functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry();
    functionRegistry.registerPattern("to_days", "to_days(?1)", basicTypeRegistry.resolve(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER));
```